# Conditionally dissect packet field in scapy

Tags: conditional-statements, decode, scapy

I have the following scapy layers:

The base layer (which is in fact SCTPChunkData() from scapy.sctp, but below is a simplified version of it):

```
class BaseProto(Packet):
    fields_desc = [ # other fields omitted...
                    FieldLenField("len", None, length_of="data", adjust = lambda pkt,x:x+6),
                    XIntField("protoId", None),
                    StrLenField("data", "", length_from=lambda pkt: pkt.len-6),
                   ]
```

And my layer defined like this:

```
MY_PROTO_ID = 19

class My_Proto(Packet):
    fields_desc = [ ShortField ("f1", None),
                    ByteField ("f2", None),
                    ByteField ("length", None), ]
```

I want to dissect the **data** field from *BaseProto* as *MyProto* if **protoId** field from *BaseProto* equals MY_PROTO_ID.

I've tried using bind_layers() for this purpose, but I then realized that this function will "tell" scapy how to to dissect the payload of the base layer, not a specific field. In my example, the *data* field will actually store all the bytes that I want to decode as *MyProto*.

Also, guess_payload_class() is not helping, as it's just a different (more powerful) version of bind_layers(), thus operating only at payload level.

Answer (score 0):

You have to chain the layers as `BaseProto()/My_Proto()` and use `bind_layers(first_layer, next_layer, condition)` to have scapy dissect them according to the condition.

Here's how it should look like.

```
PROTO_IDS = {
    19: 'my_proto',
    # define all other proto ids
}

class BaseProto(Packet):
    name = "BaseProto"
    fields_desc = [ # other fields omitted...
                    FieldLenField("len", None, length_of="data", adjust = lambda pkt,x:x+6),
                    IntEnumField("protoId", 19, PROTO_IDS),
                    #StrLenField("data", "", length_from=lambda pkt: pkt.len-6), #<-- will be the next layer, extra data will show up as Raw or PADD
                   ]

class My_Proto(Packet):
    name = "MyProto Sublayer"
    fields_desc = [ ShortField ("f1", None),
                    ByteField ("f2", None),
                    ByteField ("length", None), ]


# BIND TCP.dport==9999 => BaseProto and BaseProto.protoId==19 to My_Proto
bind_layers(TCP, BaseProto, dport=9999)
# means: if BaseProto.protoId==19: dissect as BaseProto()/My_Proto()
bind_layers(BaseProto, My_Proto, {'protoId':19})

#example / testing
bytestr = str(BaseProto()/My_Proto())    # build
BaseProto(bytestr).show()                # dissect
```

As a reference have a look at the [scapy-ssl_tls](https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls/blob/master/scapy_ssl_tls/ssl_tls.py) layer implementation as they're pretty much exercising everything you need.